# Sync Mercurial and SVN repositories

Tags: svn, mercurial, hgsubversion

I have to maintain two repositories. 
One is mercurial and another is SVN. I want to sync both these repo with the history maintained.

Few people will push code to mercurial and few will use SVN. So periodically we want to sync both the repos.

I tried with hgsubversion, but found I can't push to remote mercurial repository with it.

is there any way of doing this?

Comment: How Mercurial repo was created? In worst case you'll get unrelated repos now (and have to re-create Mercurial mirror by cloning SVN-repo)

Comment: I think someone needs to put his fist down and choose one. It's counter-productive to have multiple systems for a single repository. Change needs to be managed better in this organization.

Answer (score 0):

The only way I can think of is to have your local working copy synced to both Subversion and Mercurial, excluding the .svn directory on Mercurial and .hg on Subversion, and make it a rule for the developers to always commit to both Subversion and Hg.

Comment: Thanks, but we can not commit to both repos. Currently I am syncing them manually with pulling changes from both repo to working copy but that does not maintain history. Different teams uses different repo so they will not commit to both repos..and I want to synch it.